# Conditional JOIN different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, conditional-statements

I want to know if a user has an entry in **any** of 2 related tables.

**Tables**

```
USER (user_id)
EMPLOYEE (id, user_id)
STUDENT (id, user_id)
```

A User may have an employee and/or student entry. How can I get that info in one query?
I tried:

```
select * from [user] u
inner join employee e 
    on e.user_id = case when e.user_id is not NULL 
                        then u.user_id 
                        else null 
                   end
inner join student s 
    on s.user_id = case when s.user_id is not NULL 
                        then u.user_id 
                        else null 
                   end
```

But it will return only users with entries in **both** tables.

#### [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90216/2)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use an outer join:

```
select *
  from USER u
  left outer join EMPLOYEE e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
  left outer join STUDENT s ON u.user_id = s.user_id
 where s.user_id is not null or e.user_id is not null
```

alternatively (if you're not interested in the data from the EMPLOYEE or STUDENT table)

```
select *
  from USER u
 where exists (select 1 from EMPLOYEE e where e.user_id = u.user_id)
    or exists (select 1 from STUDENT s  where s.user_id = u.user_id)
```

Comment: To make it a bit fancier, I would write `where coalesce(s.user_id, e.user_id) is not null` instead of `where s.user_id is not null or e.user_id is not null`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get all user data together You might have:

```
SELECT 
    user_id
    ,'Employee' AS Source
FROM 
    employee
UNION 
SELECT 
    user_id
    ,'Student' AS Source
FROM 
    student
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90216/22

Which can also be done with a full join and a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(e.user_id,s.user_id) AS user_id
    ,CASE WHEN e.user_id IS NULL THEN 'Student' 
        ELSE 'Employee'
    END AS SOURCE
FROM 
    employee AS e 
    FULL JOIN student AS s
        ON s.user_id = e.user_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90216/29

the latter will combine people who are both students adn employees into one row and call them and employee. compare:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2aa3e/1
and
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2aa3e/2

where I have made user 1 a student and a employee

Answer (score 6):

Such solution also can help you.

```
SELECT  S.*, P.*

,CASE
    WHEN S.ShipmentType = 'import' THEN SP.SupplierName
    WHEN S.ShipmentType = 'export' THEN C.CustomerName
END AS ShipmentDesination

FROM            tblShippments   S 
INNER JOIN      tblProducts     P   ON S.productId = P.productID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCustomers    C   ON S.companyId = C.customerId AND S.ShipmentType = 'export'
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSuppliers    SP  ON S.companyId = SP.supplierId AND S.ShipmentType = 'import'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you look at employee and student tables as one, you can use left join:

```
select * 
from user u
left join 
(
   select 'Employee' as UserType,
          id,
          user_id
     from employee e 
    union all
   select 'Student',
          id,
          user_id
     from student s 
) r
  ON u.user_id = r.user_id
```

Comment: Best solution. UNION ALL will solve all conditional works... Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about UNION which you write as 2 separate SELECT statements

For example:

`SELECT * FROM User U
    JOIN Employee E ON E.User_Id = U.User_Id
UNION
SELECT * FROM User U
    JOIN student S ON S.User_Id = U.User_Id`

I couldn't see why you needed the CASE statement it looked superfluous.  If you wanted all Users and to show nulls then use LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

work  for mysql v5.6+
schema:

```
CREATE TABLE USER (user_id INT);
CREATE TABLE employee (id INT, user_id INT);
CREATE TABLE student (id INT, user_id INT);

INSERT INTO USER SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO USER SELECT 2;
INSERT INTO USER SELECT 3;
INSERT INTO USER SELECT 4;

INSERT INTO employee SELECT 1, 1;
INSERT INTO employee SELECT 2, 4;

INSERT INTO student SELECT 1, 2;
```

first solution
,full outer join does not work  for mysql v5.6+:

```
 SELECT 
    IF(e.user_id IS NULL,s.user_id,e.user_id) AS user_id
    ,CASE WHEN e.user_id IS NULL THEN 'Student' 
        ELSE 'Employee'
    END AS SOURCE
FROM 
    employee AS e 
    LEFT JOIN student AS s
        ON (s.user_id = e.user_id)
    UNION
        SELECT 
    IF(e.user_id IS NULL,s.user_id,e.user_id) AS user_id
    ,CASE WHEN e.user_id IS NULL THEN 'Student' 
        ELSE 'Employee'
    END AS SOURCE
    FROM 
    employee AS e 
     RIGHT JOIN student AS s
        ON (s.user_id = e.user_id)
```

alternative solution:

```
SELECT   IF(e.user_id IS NULL,s.user_id,e.user_id) AS user_id,
 CASE WHEN e.user_id IS NULL THEN 'Student' 
            ELSE 'Employee'
        END AS SOURCE
 FROM   USER AS u
 LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e ON (u.user_id = e.user_id) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN student s ON (u.user_id = s.user_id) 
 WHERE s.user_id IS NOT NULL OR e.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

other, alternative solution:

```
 SELECT u.user_id,SOURCE 
FROM USER u
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT 'Employee' AS SOURCE,id,user_id FROM employee e 
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Student',id,user_id  FROM student s 
) r ON u.user_id = r.user_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT   OrderID, Quantity,  O.ProductID , ProductName,
CASE
WHEN Quantity > 3 THEN 'The quantity is More than 3'
WHEN Quantity = 3 THEN 'The quantity is Equal to  3'
ELSE 'The quantity is Less than 3'
END AS QuantityText

FROM            tb_OrderDetail O 
INNER JOIN      tb_Product     P   ON O.ProductID = P.ProductID
```

Comment: Please give more details about your solution. Posting just code is not a good way to answer a question.