# In SQL Server I want to do a join only if a field meets a certain criteria

Tags: sql, case

I am not sure how to say this but say tbl1 is a large group of products and tbl2 has a bunch of accessories that will match up to the products. There are two id types: ID and PRODUCT. When tbl1.idtype=PRODUCT then there is usually another ID provided in tbl1 called subGroupID. I am trying to link them on ID, and if they happen to have a PRODUCT id, then link tbl2 id to tbl1 subGroup ID.

```
Select * from tbl1, tbl2
where tb1.idtype=tb2.idtype
and tbl1.id=tbl2.id

if tbl1.idtype=PRODUCT, then join on tbl1.subgroupID=tbl2.id, else don't try to do this join.
```

I suspect you should use a case when statement here, but I keep getting errors .

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279116/conditional-join-different-tables

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is really what I am looking for. I apologize for my inability to pose my problem in a clearer way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to interpret this question. One way is that you want to see all PRODUCT types and you further want to join on the subgroupID field instead of the normal ID field.

```
select ...
from   tbl1
join   tbl2
  on   tbl2.idtype = tbl1.idtype
  and  tbl2.id = tbl1.subgroupID
where  tbl1.idtype = PRODUCT;
```

However, you could also be wanting to join in general and just use the alternate field for PRODUCTs.

```
select ...
from   tbl1
join   tbl2
  on   tbl2.idtype = tbl1.idtype
  and  tbl2.id = case when tbl1.idtype = PRODUCT
         then tbl1.subgroupID
         else tbl1.id
         end
where  ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe looks like a N:M relationship or if you prefer a many to many relationship.  That means a product can have zero or many accessories and an accessory can fit zero or many products.  If so, you should use 3 tables : Product ProductsAccessories and Accessory.  Something like :

```
Product 
  ProductId  PK
  Name
  ...

ProductsAccessories
  ProductsAccessoriesID  PK
  ProductId  FK
  AccessoryId FK

Accessory
  AccessoryId PK
  Name
  ...
```

That would be the best way to do it.

As for your question it is very hard to answer the way you asked it but I think you are looking for something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM 
  tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON 
  tbl1.subgroupID = tbl2.subgroupID AND
  tbl1.idType = 'PRODUCT'
```

The key word you are probably looking for is LEFT JOIN.  It will keep in the result set the products that do not have accessories.